# SQLAlchemy connection autoclose on function failure

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, connection

Say I have the following function:

```
@app.route("/function")
def function():
    engine = sqlalchemy.getEngine() # simplified to indicate we get an engine
    connection = engine.connect()
    result = utils.doThings(connection)
    connection.close()
```

If utils.doThings fails and my api call would usually just crash and write a report of the crash. Will my connection remain alive indefinitely? Or will overtime, the database prune the connections that have been idle? Is there a better way to handle this behavior than having a try except block which closes the connection on except?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections are closed before they are deleted as they fall out of scope. Since the connection is created in the handler function, when the function raises an error and exits, your connection will become ready for the garbage collector to delete.

However, two points to add, the engine of SQLAlchemy manages a pool of connection and could/should be share by the different handlers, and the connection can be used as a context manager which will ensure the connection is deleted for you (see [the tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#getting-a-connection)).

All in all, this is what your Flask app could look like:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite://")

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    try:
        with engine.connect() as con:
            result = con.execute(sa.text("SELECT 'hello'")).scalars().one()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)  # please log better than this
    return result.encode("utf-8"), 200
```

Comment: To clarify - if my function failed, that connection would be marked for garbage collection and python would delete the connection which would close it on the db side?
Second, is there a benefit to doing a with engine.connect() as con as opposed to running a try except where the except closes the connection?
Finally, my engine is not made within my function, it is grabbed depending on the user who logs in. Is this what you meant by the handler?

Comment: Additionally, how long does it take the db to clean up stale connections? Is it at all feasible to leave that to the database or is it best practice to clean up server side?

Comment: If your function as you wrote it failed, it would leave the connection to be garbage collected. The benefit of using the context manager is that it does all the try/except work for you, use it. Your function is what I called the handler, as it handles a request to an endpoint. Finally, you definitely do not want to leave closing connections to the database, it's bad practice and might happen manually depending on the database you use.

Comment: I want to know if an error occurs - in the with x as y manner, how do we log errors?

Comment: The context manager raises the exception, but the connection will have been closed properly. See my edit.

Comment: Haha gotcha, don't worry my logs are better, this is a very simplistic view of the application